# Unity additive Scenes + Navmesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I have 3 scenes in unity 5.5.1f :

1. Scene base is permanent. (Contollers + Player + Manager...) + navmesh of scene 1.
2. Scene 1 + navmesh in his own scene folder.
3. Scene 2 + navmesh in his own scene folder.

When i start the game. I have my base + scene 1 with the right navmesh.
But i think it use the navmesh of the base scene (navmesh scene1).

When i go to the scene 2, scene 2 dont load the navmesh of the scene 2.

I have the navmesh of my base scene (navmesh scene1) in the scene 2 too.

I tryed to delete the navmesh of the base scene but all the enemies are freeze if i do that.

Please how can i fix this. ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why dont you remove navmesh of scene 1 from your base scene `Scene base is permanent. (Controllers + Player + Manager...) `

Comment: Like i said , i tryed to remove, but all ennemies are freezed if i do it.

Comment: i have instances of enemies that spawn in base scene. I would like to have the right navmesh in base scene too when i go to scene 2.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution :

I deleted all the navmesh in all scenes.

I loaded all scenes in the inspector and then i moved the complete scene 2 in another place in scene window.

So i can see both scene in scene window and i have my base scene too.

After that, i baked a new navmesh. Now i can see the navmesh of all my scenes.

I did like i have read in manual at this link :

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html